# Why baking soda neutralize the flavor of coconut oil?

Tags: fats

I discovered recently that adding baking soda to a recipe can neutralize the strong flavours of the coconut oil. Does anyone know how it is working and what is, in a simple way, the chemical reaction for this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Seems like you're using unrefined coconut oil? From my memory baking soda could neutralise the lauric acid. Actually to convert unrefined to refined they put it through a process that has a sub-process of neutralisation to help reduce the strong flavour!

Comment: On the light of Desai comment OP you might specify it the flavor reduced was the coconut one or any other taste/note.